# transform rotate and padding behaviour

Tags: css

I've got an image inside a button which is rotated `180deg` and has `padding-right` set. The problem is that actually the padding appears on the left instead of right and I am sure this behaviour is caused by the rotate. It kind of makes sense, but at the same time doesn't. Is this expected? Can't see anything mentioned on [W3C website](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/).

```css
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button img {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="" role="presentation" />Back</button>
```

Comment: We can't see the image.

Comment: Also, everything associated with `img` is rotated. So yes, it does make sense. But then again, that's an opinion. It's the expected output. Say for example you rotate it 45 degrees. The padding would need to rotate with the image, otherwise, it wouldn't look good. If you need the padding to stay in place, try adding a `div` containing the `img` and add padding to the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is as expected. `transform rotate` is being applied on the element itself. since the `img` element also has css styling (beside the image source), those are also being counted when rotating. So, having a padding will cause also the padding to be rotated.

In your case, if the `180deg` rotation is constant, you could just use `padding-left`, so when the element is being rotated, it will appear on the right.

Another option is wrapping the image with another `div` element and apply the padding to the `div` instead on the image, and remain only the rotation on that `img` element.

Answer (score 1):

> The transform CSS property lets you rotate, scale, skew, or translate an element. It modifies the coordinate space of the CSS visual formatting model. - MDN

The `transform: rotate()` property rotates almost every property that an element has.

See this example:

If I set `margin-top: 1rem;` and `padding-bottom: 1rem;` it will rotate them.

```css
div {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>I'm an element!</div>
```

And if you open the HTML source, you will see that the margin is at the bottom and the padding at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected behavior.

Consider the following `border-right` example, it will show up on the **left** side:

```css
div {
    background: grey;
    border-right: 1em solid red;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

To prevent this, apply the padding on the `<img>`, and rotate an parent element (or vice versa):

```css
button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button .rotateContainer {
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}
button img {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
<div class='rotateContainer'>
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="" role="presentation" /></div>Back</button>
```